# How to prove ${\lambda _n}\left( {{X^T}AX} \right) \le {\lambda _n}\left( A \right){\rho ^2}\left( X \right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

I am trying to prove the following inequality

$${\lambda _n}\left( {{X^T}AX} \right) \le {\lambda _n}\left( A \right){\rho ^2}\left( X \right)$$
where $\rho$ is the spectral radius of a matrix and $\lambda_n$ is the smallest eigenvalue. Also, the matrix $A$ is positive definite and $X$ is negative definite.

Comment: You can use the result of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042710/a-quotient-representation-of-singular-values-of-symmetric-matrix).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I prove ${\lambda _n}\left( {{X^T}AX} \right) \leqslant \left\| X \right\|_F^2{\lambda _n}\left( A \right)$ where $A$ is a PD matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473730/how-can-i-prove-lambda-n-left-xtax-right-leqslant-left-x-right)

Answer (score 1):

We may assume that $\lambda_n(X^TAX)>0,$ as otherwise the inequality is obvious. Thus $X$ and $A$ are invertible.
For any symmetric matrix $S$ there holds
$$\lambda_n(S)=\min\{\langle Su,u\rangle \,:\,\|u\|=1\}$$
Hence
$$\lambda_n(X^TAX)=\min\{\langle X^TAXu,u\rangle \,:\,\|u\|=1\}$$
As $X$ is invertible, there exists $v$  such that $$AXv=\lambda_n(A)Xv\quad \|v\|=1$$
Therefore
$$\lambda_n(X^TAX)\le \langle X^TAXv,v\rangle =\lambda_n(A) \langle X^TXv,v\rangle \le \lambda_n(A)\|X\|^2$$

By assumption $X$ is negative definite, hence $X$ is symmetric. Thus $\rho(X)=\|X\|.$ Summarizing we get
$$\lambda_n(X^TAX)\le \lambda_n(A)\rho(X)^2$$

**Remark** The assumption $A\ge 0$ is essential. Indeed, let $$X=\begin{pmatrix} -1& 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,\quad A=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $X^TAX=0$ and $\lambda_2(A)\rho(X)^2=-1.$

Comment: I forgot to add that $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Question has been edited

Comment: does it still hold if the matrix $X$ is not symmetric but still have all eigenvalues negative?

Comment: I do not know. In your question you have assumed that $X$ is negative definite, i.e. $-X$ is positive definite, i.e. it is symmetric in particular. In my answer assumption $X\le 0$ is not important. Just symmetry  is applied. Or normality of $X.$

Comment: I have simplified the reasoning substantially. It should be easier to determine if the assumption of normality of $X$ is essential or not.